# Can overlayFS support more than two layers?

Tags: overlayfs

As far as i read documentation the overlayFS supports two layers - upper and lower. But is there possibility to increase it to three layers?

Answer (score 7):

short answer: yes

long answer: from the sections ["Upper and Lower"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) and "Multiple lower layers":

> "...The lower filesystem can be any filesystem supported by Linux and does
>   not need to be writable.  The lower filesystem even be another
>   overlayfs. ..."

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
Multiple lower layers can now be given using the the colon (":") as a
separator character between the directory names.  For example:

  mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/lower1:/lower2:/lower3 /merged
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt